# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: bash

I'm beginner at bash, and probably missing something very basic.
I get the following syntax error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

when i run the following bash script:

```
case "$OSTYPE" in
  darwin*)
    cmake . -DPLATFORMTARGET=x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG  -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/Users/$(whoami)/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/lib/cmake"
  linux*)
    cmake . -DPLATFORMTARGET=x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/Users/$(whoami)/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake"
make clean
make -j4
```

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case

Comment: Each branch of a `case` statement must end with `;;`. Also, the `esac` keyword that tells where the `case` statement ends is missing. Read about the [syntax of the `case` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to end the switch-branch with ;; like

```
case "$x" in
  a)
    echo "a"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "not a"
    ;;
esac
```

and end the case with esac.